# How to check if command prompt is open using VB Script?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, vbscript, window

How to check if command prompt/window is open using VB Script?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 - Setup Project, and I want my VB Script to check if the command line is closed, and when it's closed, it will raise an error and terminate the whole installation.

Comment: Do you mean to do with VBscript or VB.net (Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Win32_ProcessStartTrace : Win32_ProcessTrace
{
  uint4 PageDirectoryBase;
  string ParentProcessName;
  uint32 ProcessID;
  string ProcessName;
  uint8 SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR[];
  uint32 SessionID;
  uint8 Sid[];
  uint8 TIME_CREATED;
};
```

This monitors starts and stops. Above properties is from starts only and same properties as below object. Also there is a stop object. My code can only do one event, there's an alternative that can do multi events but you have to set up event handlers.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
Loop
```

You can get extra info from the Process class.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    'Get process id you want from other script
    If obj.ProcessID = 1004 Then
        msgbox objItem.ProcessID & " " & FormatDateTime(CDate(objItem.CreationDate))
    EndIf
Next
```

These are it's properties. It also has methods.

```
class Win32_Process : CIM_Process
{
  string Caption;
  string CommandLine;
  string CreationClassName;
  datetime CreationDate;
  string CSCreationClassName;
  string CSName;
  string Description;
  string ExecutablePath;
  uint16 ExecutionState;
  string Handle;
  uint32 HandleCount;
  datetime InstallDate;
  uint64 KernelModeTime;
  uint32 MaximumWorkingSetSize;
  uint32 MinimumWorkingSetSize;
  string Name;
  string OSCreationClassName;
  string OSName;
  uint64 OtherOperationCount;
  uint64 OtherTransferCount;
  uint32 PageFaults;
  uint32 PageFileUsage;
  uint32 ParentProcessId;
  uint32 PeakPageFileUsage;
  uint64 PeakVirtualSize;
  uint32 PeakWorkingSetSize;
  uint32 Priority;
  uint64 PrivatePageCount;
  uint32 ProcessId;
  uint32 QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
  uint32 QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
  uint32 QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
  uint32 QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
  uint64 ReadOperationCount;
  uint64 ReadTransferCount;
  uint32 SessionId;
  string Status;
  datetime TerminationDate;
  uint32 ThreadCount;
  uint64 UserModeTime;
  uint64 VirtualSize;
  string WindowsVersion;
  uint64 WorkingSetSize;
  uint64 WriteOperationCount;
  uint64 WriteTransferCount;
};
```

Her's a sample script from Help showing how to do multiple events handlers.

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set EventSink = WScript.CreateObject( _
    "WbemScripting.SWbemSink","SINK_")

objWMIservice.ExecNotificationQueryAsync EventSink, _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessTrace WITHIN 10"
WScript.Echo "Waiting for events..."

i = 0
While (True)
    Wscript.Sleep(1000)
Wend

Sub SINK_OnObjectReady(objObject, objAsyncContext)
    Wscript.Echo "Win32_ProcessTrace event has occurred."
    i = i+1
    If i = 3 Then WScript.Quit 0 
End Sub
```